# hotkey script that copies all the text in my open notepad file to a clipboard and then closes the file

Tags: copy-paste, vbscript

Please. I am new to VBS and may not be saying this right but I need a script with a keyboard shortcut that copies all the text in my open notepad file to the clipboard and then closes the notepad file.